# laptop strange shutdown issue

Tags: shutdown

When I choose shutdown option from the right top menu, Ubuntu is closing the session but coming back to the login screen. This is not a normal behaviour as Ubuntu should shutdown.
But when I press the hardware shutdown button, I select shut-down on the screen and the laptop shuts down. that is fine.

Ubuntu 14.10

Answer (score 0):

If any other remote user is logged in into your PC, or any software that runs using an another session, then Ubuntu will behave as you are telling its not an issue it actually prevents you to disconnect the remote user, but if you do shut down from power button then it will do force shut-down and disconnect the session from any other users.

before shutting down check whether any other session is still running.

by the following commands

> who

or

> w

and kill those session and try a normal shut-down.

Comment: I can see 2 users on the terminal, I don't understand as I'm the only one to have logged in, there are 2 users with my name. 1 = TTY :0 and 2 = TTY :Pts/4

Comment: type `ps -ft pts/4` and kill the process by `kill <PID>` and try a normal shut-down.

Comment: kill <PID> returns syntax error

Comment: terminal ask for processus login

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195470/how-to-kill-the-tty-in-unix

Comment: "fred@fred-X201EP:~$ ps -ft pts/4
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
fred      5625  5615  0 13:05 pts/4    00:00:00 bash
fred      5730  5625  0 13:06 pts/4    00:00:00 ps -ft pts/4
fred@fred-X201EP:~$ kill 5730
bash: kill: (5730) - Aucun processus de ce type"

Comment: ps -ft pts/4 returns 2 lines, if i kill the seconde line with ID processus it returns : no process type, if I kill the first line, nothing happens, the 2 lines are still here if I type w

Comment: It seems Ok to have 2 lines after 'w' in the terminal, 1 line for the upstartuser, when I logged in and the second for the terminal I typed in 'W'. So the shut down issue must be seached elsewhere.

Comment: yeah you can have more than two also but with the same user only pts/no may change , but if you found any other user then this might give you shut-down issue, but here it seems its not that problem.